# Blazor InputFile provides filename without path

Tags: server, upload, blazor

I'm working on my first Blazor (server) project and I've run into a snag with uploading files. I have very simple test bed markup:

```
<InputFile OnChange="@ImportFile" />
```

And the method:

```
private void ImportFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
   var fileToUpload = e.File;
   var filename = fileToUpload.Name;
}
```

When I select a file from an arbitrary folder, the value of 'filename' in the ImportFile method is just the filename including the extension, but there's no path. I have searched for a solution to this dilemma without success.

So, when I try to read the file, the system is looking for it in the project's folder instead of the folder the file actually resides in. I get an error like "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\repos\foobar\Test.txt'"

I hope I'm just missing something simple here... uploading files is such a common task, so this seems like it should be straightforward.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your Client app is not allowed to know the path. And it usually does not reside on your Server.

Comment: could you please share your code which you used to read the file then get the error? here's the [detailed document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for blazor file upload.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/file-system-access#resolving_the_path_of_an_item_in_a_directory

Comment: I finally realized that I have to take the file object returned by FileInput and convert it to a Stream.

Comment: I finally realized that I have to take the file object returned by FileInput and convert it to a Stream. I create a byte array of the size of the file, use OpenReadStream().ReadAsync to populate the byte array, and then convert the byte array to a Stream. The problem appears to be that the byte array consists of all zeros.